# Does MSE provide which bugs are being solved?

Tags: support, meta, bug-reports

I saw many questions on MSE which are under [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag and having many upvotes. Many times moderators and 10k+ users approve it as bug. And Many time people reports same bugs under different title and descriptions. Many sites provides bug reporting feature and it's status(familiar site facebook).  So same questions can be deleted or closed immediately.

- Does MSE provides which bugs are approved and will be solved?
- Which bugs are solved until now?

You can see many bugs at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see special tags applied to the questions that indicate their status. These tags are rendered in a different color because they can only be added by moderators. Their names indicate what decisions was made regarding that particular bug.

The status tags include:

- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) Indicates that a submitted issue is actually due to the existing design of the system and is not considered erroneous behaviour. In other words, "it's not a bug, it's a feature!"
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Indicates that a feature request has been implemented, a bug has been fixed, or another type of request has been processed.
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) Indicates that a request (usually a feature request) has been considered, but will not be implemented.
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) Indicates that the issue will be reviewed in the future.
- [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) Indicates that a reported erroneous behavior cannot be reproduced by the development team.
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) Indicates that a feature request has been considered and received positively enough that its implementation has been placed in the development queue.
- [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) Indicates that the symptoms of a bug report have been reproduced/confirmed by the development team.
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) Indicates that a feature request or possible solutions to a bug are set to be internally reviewed.

To see all of the bugs that have been marked completed, add that tag to the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag in your search query, [like so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+bug).

Comment: My 2nd question got answer: question having tag status-completed are solved. What about 1st question?

Comment: @Som: The [meta-tag:status-planned] tag is the answer to your first question.

Comment: @CodyGray: Nice answer....All describes about bugs. But does every bug  have atleast one tag out of it? If so, then how hard you are working I can imagine.

Comment: @Som: I suppose not *all* bugs have these tags. Those are the ones the developers haven't gotten around to yet. And yes, I assume they're fairly busy—they do get paid to maintain and improve the sites.