# Why are some tags in a different color?

Tags: support, tags, meta

Some of the tags in the Stack Overflow tag list have a different color. Such as below:

> [image: tag color]

Why do some of these tags have another color background?

Comment: #These are moderator only tags.

See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/47640#47640

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## These are moderator only tags.

See [How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/47640#47640)

And also this can be responses of moderation or feature request or discussion.

See this also [Does MSE provide which bugs are being solved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125265/does-mso-provide-which-bugs-are-being-solved)